# UPDATING a section of string for column

Tags: sql, sql-server

We have the following:

```
create table #a_table 
(names char(10))
insert into #a_table
values
('A;B;C;'),
('B;C;D;'),
('A;B;C;E;'),
('A;C;'),
('A;B;'),
('A;'),
('A;C;E;');
```

How do we `update` the table and change every instance of C; with X;Y;

So
A;B;C; would become A;B;X;Y;
A;C;E; would become A;X;Y;E;
etc.

---

**EDIT**

A standard `ANSI` approach that is compatible on SQL-server would be prefereable.

Comment: @AlmaDo standard solution is fine

Comment: @whytheq Alma was asking whether you're using MSSQL, MySQL or any other database software

Comment: @Liath ...that is why I replied that standard (as in ANSI _standard_) is fine. Running sql-server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This all depends on which database you're actually using. In MSSQL Server You can use the SQL [replace](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186862.aspx) function

```
update #a_table set names = replace(names, 'C;', 'X;Y;')
```

Other databases have similar functions (such as the MySQL one [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_replace))

Comment: What if DMBS isn't MSSQL? What if `C` will be at the end of string? (like `A;B;C`)

Comment: @AlmaDo, yeah I've just expanded with MySQL equivalent. Hopefully the OP will expand

Comment: @AlmaDo re your second point - the OP's posted actually had C; at the end of the string so I'm assuming it's always semi-colon terminated

Comment: @Liath - yes always seperated by `;`